# Exception while reading from stream in npgsql

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

We have a table having one of the columns as a **text** datatype and having only 3 records. We execute an Update query on text column using ExecuteNonQuery() and it throws an error "Exception while reading from the stream". Error occurs randomly which means some times the query is executed and sometimes it throws an error but the maximum ratio is of error like it throws error 9 times out of 10. We are using `Npgsql -Version 4.0.4`  and `PostgreSQL version 11.1` running on `windows 2012 R2`
. Also, we tried setting up the timeout as 0 but the error is thrown immediately so it is not related to timeout error as well. 
 Below is our exception.

```
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlReadBuffer.<>c__DisplayClass31_0.<g__EnsureLong|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<>c__DisplayClass161_0.<g__ReadMessageLong|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.d__46.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.d__100.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at Npgsql.PostgresDatabaseInfo.d__13.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Npgsql.PostgresDatabaseInfo.d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Npgsql.PostgresDatabaseInfoFactory.d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDatabaseInfo.d__79.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.d__150.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.d__149.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Npgsql.ConnectorPool.d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.<>c__DisplayClass32_0.<g__OpenLong|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.Open()
   at DataAccessLayer.Providers.Executors.PostgreSQL.ExecuteQuery(PreparedStatement`1 preparedStatement, Int32 timeout) in C:\code\Framework\DataAccessLayer\Providers\Executors\PostgreSQL.cs:line 64
   at DataAccessLayer.Providers.PostgreSQL.ExecuteQuery(IExecuteQuerySupport command, Int32 timeout) in C:\main\code\Framework\DataAccessLayer\Providers\Modules\PostgreSQLServer.cs:line 26
   at BAL.Base.RolesManagement.Roles.GetDatabaseRole(Int64 userID) in C:\main\code\BusinessAccessLayer\BAL\Base\RolesManagement\Roles.cs:line 398
   at API.Controllers.MyWorkspacesController.ConnectGroup(Int64 groupID) in C:\main\code\Web\API\Controllers\MyWorkspacesController.cs:line 390
   --- End of exception stack trace ---
    Message : Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
StackTrace :    at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlReadBuffer.<>c__DisplayClass31_0.<g__EnsureLong|0>d.MoveNext()
    --- End of inner exception stack trace --- 
    Message : A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
StackTrace :    at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Comment: Your message includes a stack trace, but not the exception message itself - you indicate that it could be a timeout message, but can you please confirm? If so, please try turning on keepalives as described here: http://www.npgsql.org/doc/keepalive.html

Comment: @ShayRojansky: The error says "Exception while reading from the stream" and the mentioned above is the stack trace. I meant to say it is not a timeout issue because the error is thrown immediately so even setting timeout will not work. Even keepalive is not an issue because it's throwing the error immediately without waiting for a time.

Comment: In general, "Exception while reading from the stream" isn't the complete exception message. Can you make sure you're doing a `ToString()` on the exception message and posting the result?

Comment: GH dup: https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/2337

Comment: The exception message is "Exception while reading from the stream" and its stack trace is as mentioned above. This is the only information we are logging in our error system.We are not logging the inner stack trace

Comment: Try to log the inner exception information as well, as it could provide valuable information about what's going on. Regardless, the random nature of this could indicate some sort of networking issue, such as connections being dropped or similar... Are your client program and database running on the same network?

Comment: Sure, we will try to log the inner exception and yes our client program and database run on the same network.

Comment: Just a question. Can this error occur due to reading and writing the same record and column at the same time? because while analyzing the queries executed we found a query which is reading the same record and column while the update query is executed.

Comment: @ShayRojansky: We checked and the provided error log contains all the inner exception stack trace as well so this is the final stack trace we have.

Comment: There's not much I can do with this information... Any way you could isolate this our into some sort of reproducible code sample? That should be reproducible if you run a scenario in a loop until it fails etc. However, there's still a good chance we'd find this to be some environment or network-related issue, so testing on a different network or server on your side may yield different results.

Comment: When you write "reading and writing the same record at the same time", do you mean from two different connections? If so then there shouldn't be a problem, database routinely have to deal with this. If you mean using the same connection for two operations at the same time, then you definitely cannot do this.

Comment: We have observed the logs of PG also at the same time we received the error we found below error on PG server If this can help you.

timestamp=2019-02-26 03:38:05.427 EST,user=student,db=student_11,app=[unknown],client=XX.XXX.XXX.XX,transaction-ID=0,session_start_timestamp=2019-02-26 03:37:59 EST,SQL_state=08006LOG:  could not receive data from client: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

Comment: The seems like it could be the PostgreSQL side of the same disconnect that you've previously posted. This could be a network issue resulting in the connection being closed, or simply Npgsql closing the connection after raising the error (and PostgreSQL reporting that).

Comment: Again, in .NET there's usually additional exception information beyond "Exception while reading from the stream" (via an inner SocketException or similar), which would help understand what's going on. But the best path forward as always is to try to reproduce this with a small console app, to see whether it reproduces outside of your regular network, and ideally to share that app with the Npgsql maintainers - the moment we can see a problem occurring we can investigate it.

Comment: If you see the above exception then it contains all the inner exception. One of them is " at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read" if this can help you.

Comment: @HardikDobariya: We are facing the same issues from the last few days, So can you please let me know what needs to be changed?

Comment: @ShayRojansky: Finally we have all the exceptions with messages. I have edited the exception.

Comment: The stack trace above contains a timeout exception, which doesn't add much information... This exception is coming from the socket layer beneath Npgsql, and saying that an answer from PostgreSQL wasn't received in the time allotted. It would be very strange if this exception were raised if the timeout were set to zero (note that difference between `Timeout`, which is about connecting, and `Command Timeout`, which is about executing queries).

Comment: Apart from that there's not much I can offer in terms of help, this is likely some sort of environmental issue in your network or similar...

Comment: @ShayRojansky: Thank you for your response. In this case, even we are stuck  Even our site is on production and this issue is troubling the users. Is it possible if you could provide us some troubleshooting steps to identify the issue in the network?

Comment: Facing similar issue on same server application. Is there anything that could be done to mitigate this.

Comment: @HardikDobariya Facing similar issues is there anything that could be done to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

We had similar problem with version `4.0.4` (well any `4.x` really).

It turned out that one of the columns that were **already stored in database** contained invalid characters or was somehow corrupted.

Simple `update <tab> set <col> = '' where id = <id>` for that one column fixed the `Exception while reading from the stream` error message.

PS. Restoring the date without suspicious UTF-8 characters didn't cause the problem to reappear.